# Can I pair lenovo wireless mouse and keyboard with a logitech unifying receiver?

Tags: usb, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I'm using two sets of wireless HID with the same laptop (one in the office, one at home). At work I have the Lenovo Keyboard and Mouse that came with the laptop and at home I have a set of Logitech stuff. As a result two of my precious few USB ports are now blocked by a dongle :-/

Is it possible to pair the Lenovo hardware with the Logitech dongle or the other way around? After searching the web for a while I found basically nothing.

Comment: Only if both sets use Bluetooth. And then you probably don't need any dongles as most laptops have a buildin Bluetooth receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably **NO**.

Both brands probably uses proprietary communication protocols which are not harmonized (no business interest of any of the companies to do so).

*(If you have a docking station in your office, you can store it's receiver there, and long term solution could be to stick to the same brand)*

Comment: +1 beat me to it. even some peripherals by logitech can't connect to a unifying receiver because it looks for certified hardware only.

Comment: I was kind of expecting this answer after literally finding nothing about this on the web. I'm actually keeping the Lenovo receiver in a docking station but most of the time so the pain is bearable :-)